Invoke-Sqlcmd is not available from within powershell script
I am not able from within .ps1 script call function Invoke-Sqlcmd.
This script is:
Install-Module -Name SqlServer
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "SQLSERVER\" -Database "MYDB" -Query "SELECT * FROM MYDB"

After I run script:
pwsh -f .\InvokeSqlCmd.ps1

I get message:
The term 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

But when I run command Invoke-Sqlcmd from general Powershell console, I can run this command without problems.
And when I run command Get-Command -Module sqlserver from within script I cannot see Invoke-Sqlcmd but when I run this command from Powershell console window I can see Invoke-Sqlcmd there.
Powershell version is
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.4.3
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.4.3
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.20348
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0

When I replace Install-Module -Name SqlServer with Import-Module -Name SqlServer I get these errors:
Import-Module: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=17.100.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'. Could not find or
load a specific file. (0x80131621)
InvalidOperation: The variable '$binaryModule' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
Import-Module: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=17.100.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'. Could not find or
load a specific file. (0x80131621)
Add-Type: Assembly with same name is already loaded
Add-Type: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=17.100.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'.
Add-Type: Assembly with same name is already loaded
Add-Type: Assembly with same name is already loaded


Installing a module doesn't import it.

You need to use Import-Module not Install-Module

Guys, I changed Install-Module with Import-Module but behaviour is the same. What means Invoke-Sqlcmd is not known.

If Import-Module didn't import the module, the module isn't installed.

Why, out of interest, are you using pswh -f? Why not just .\InvokeSqlCmd.ps1? (I assume you're already in a command line.)

"but behaviour is the same." that edit you just did clearly demonstrates different behaviour...

If, by "general Powershell console", you mean PowerShell 5.x then you should be aware that the Install-Module paths for -Scope User are different between PowerShell 5.x and 7 (pwsh). Check the results of $Env:PSModulePath -split (';') in both versions to ensure that the paths reported in pwsh exist and are accessible to your account.

@ThomA You are correct, behaviour is different (another messages) but result is the same (InvokeSqlCmd.ps1 can not be run). Just .\InvokeSqlCmd.ps1 is functional but I run this command from Task scheduler and that's why I run this command with pwsh -f ... because I want use PowerShell Core 7 instead of default PowerShell 5.

@AlwaysLearning general Powershell console I mean console window with PowerShell 7.

What account are you running the task under from Task Scheduler? As mentioned by @AlwaysLearning , installs can be scoped to the user, so if you installed module scoped to your user, but you're running the task under a different user, that module won't exist.

@ThomA account I am running the task under from Task Scheduler is the same account I use for these examples. But in my opinion this is not account issue, because with the same account is functional (run InvokeSqlCmd.ps1) and non functional (run pwsh -f .\InvokeSqlCmd.ps1). Something is wrong when with pwsh -f ... script is running.

Sometimes things depend on having the user's profile (and registry) loaded, which isn't a sure thing with Task Scheduler items. On the general tab of your scheduled task do you have "Run whether user is logged on or not" selected and "Do not store password" unticked?

In the end I rewrote my script with sqlcmd (go) command, instead of use of the PowerShell module SqlServer.

I guess there is a module scope conflict. Check the $env:PSModulePath for installed versions and remove duplicate (/older) ones. Or try Using module SqlServer instead.

Best way of debugging is to use SQL Server Management Studio and check the log files in the explorer un Management.  There should be a login for each time the powershell does a query. The log file will show the user/group for the login.  Compare the results when it works and doesn't work to see if the user/group changes.
